# Transformation of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X\sim Exp(\lambda), \,\,\lambda>0$ and $Y=X^3$.
Find the probability density function of $Y$.

I've tried with the formula $f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))*\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y) \right|$, but I can't seem to find the right answer.

Comment: Please show your work so that we can point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply applying the formula you showed you must reach the solution....

$$y=x^3$$

$$x=y^{1/3}$$

$$x'=\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{y^2}}$$

substitute and get the solution

Comment: So I will get the PDF

$f_Y(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda*y^{1/3}}*\frac{1}{3*y^{2/3}}$

Comment: @Overkill123 :please amend your previous anwer inserting the solution you reached so we can check it

Comment: I've edited the first comment :)

Comment: @Overkill123 that's correct